# Function to set textarea value - additional runs through append data instead of replace it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea, whose value I want to set with a function. When I first click the button to set the value, the value populates correctly.

If I then click the button to set the value again, using a different option from the list of radio buttons, the value in the textarea is not cleared and replaced with the new data - data resultiing from the logic in the JS code is appended to the data in the textarea, instead of replacing what is already there.

I have tried to clear the textarea value with:

```
document.getElementById("output").value = '';
```

But that doesn't clear it.

**HTML:**

```
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioActivity" value="valActivity"> Activity
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioFlags" value="arrFlags"> Flags
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioFood" value="arrFood"> Food
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioNature" value="arrNature"> Nature
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioObjects" value="arrObjects"> Objects
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioPeople" value="arrPeople"> People
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioLetters" value="arrLetters"> Letters
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioSymbols" value="arrSymbols"> Symbols
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="myArray" id="radioTravel" value="arrTravel"> Travel
    </label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemSet" value="10" />

    <button id="rdio"> Check Radio </button>

    <textarea id="output" class="form-control" style="width:95%; height:500px; margin-top:20px;"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
    var myCols = 2;

    var arrActivity = ["alien monster","man in business suit levitating","fencer","horse racing","skier","snowboarder","golfer","surfer","rowboat","swimmer"];
    var arrFlags = ["ascension","andorra","the united arab emirates","afghanistan","antigua and barbuda","anguilla","albania","armenia","angola","antarctica"];
    var arrFood = ["grapes","melon","watermelon","tangerine","lemon","banana","pineapple","red apple","green apple","pear"];
    var arrNature = ["see-no-evil monkey","hear-no-evil monkey","speak-no-evil monkey","splashing sweat symbol","dash symbol","monkey face","monkey","gorilla","dog face","dog"];
    var arrObjects = ["skull and crossbones","love letter","bomb","hole","shopping bags","prayer beads","gem stone","hocho","amphora","world map"];
    var arrPeople = ["grinning face","grinning face with smiling eyes","face with tears of joy","rolling on the floor laughing","smiling face with open mouth","smiling face with open mouth and smiling eyes","smiling face with open mouth and cold sweat","smiling face with open mouth and tightly-closed eyes","winking face","smiling face with smiling eyes"];
    var arrLetters = ["letter a","letter b","letter c","letter d","letter e","letter f","letter g","letter h","letter i","letter j"];
    var arrSymbols = ["eye in speech bubble","heart with arrow","heavy black heart","beating heart","broken heart","two hearts","sparkling heart","growing heart","blue heart","green heart"];
    var arrTravel = ["racing car","racing motorcycle","silhouette of japan","snow capped mountain","mountain","volcano","mount fuji","camping","beach with umbrella","desert"];

    var arrNew = [];

    function boom()
    {

        if (document.getElementById("radioActivity").checked) {
            y = arrActivity;
        } else if(document.getElementById("radioFlags").checked) {
            y = arrFlags;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioFood").checked) {
            y = arrFood;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioNature").checked) {
            y = arrNature;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioObjects").checked) {
            y = arrObjects;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioPeople").checked) {
            y = arrPeople;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioLetters").checked) {
            y = arrLetters;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioSymbols").checked) {
            y = arrSymbols;
        } else if (document.getElementById("radioTravel").checked) {
            y = arrTravel;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i+=myCols) {
            arrNew.push(
                y.slice(i, i+myCols)
            );
        }

        // attempts to clear the output...
        // op = '';
        document.getElementById("output").value = '';

        // set the textarea output
        op = JSON.stringify(arrNew, null, 4);
        document.getElementById('output').value = op;

    }

    var z = document.getElementById('rdio');
    z.addEventListener("click", boom);
```

Codepen to show issue:
https://codepen.io/paperknees/pen/JrgNzp

Comment: Your code to clear out the textarea is ok, but you are not reinitializing the arrNew variable and so it gets more and more stuff pushed into it every time the button is clicked (and that's getting displayed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrNew should be declared as an empty array inside the function call every time.

```
function boom() {

  var arrNew = [];

  ...
```